# My ggplot includes geom_boxplot and geom_line, but it does not show the legend for the geom_line part. How can I add it please?

Tags: ggplot2, legend, boxplot, line-plot, geom

My ggplot includes geom_boxplot and geom_line, but it only shows the legend for the boxplot part but does not show the legend for the geom_line part. How can I add it please?

Note: The boxplot and the line were made from two different data sources, but shown in one graph.

I really need help with this please, thank you!

Here is the code:

```
library(ggnewscale)

    bplot6 <- ggplot(seasonalmerge_neale1989) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = date, y = values, group = date, fill = `Data Source`), width = 2, outlier.shape = NA,
               lwd = 0.1) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  ylim(0,1.2) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(family="serif", size = 8),
    axis.text.y = element_text(family="serif", size = 8),
    legend.title = element_text(family="serif", size = 8),
    legend.text = element_text(family="serif", size = 8),
    plot.title = element_text(family="serif", face="bold", size = 8, hjust = 0.5)) +
  ggtitle("(f)")+
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(data=pointframe, aes(x= pointdate, y=pointvar), colour="gold", size=1, method = "lm", se=FALSE)
# +theme_classic()+scale_linetype_manual(values=bplot6, name="Data Source: ", labels=c("Ceres", "Landsat", "FAO"))+ theme(legend.position = "bottom")

bplot6
```

[image of boxplots and line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXRs6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A color must be specified inside an aesthetic in order for there to be a legend.
Moving `colour` inside `aes()` will build a legend automatically. Then we can adjust the labels and colors with `scale_color_manual`. Reproducing your code using `iris` data.

```
library(ggnewscale)
bplot6 <- ggplot(iris) +
geom_boxplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width , group = Species, fill = `Species`), width = 2, outlier.shape = NA,lwd = 0.1) +
xlab("") +
ylab("") +
#ylim(0,1.2) + you can use it as per your requirement
theme(
axis.text.x = element_text(family="serif", size = 8),
axis.text.y = element_text(family="serif", size = 8),
legend.title = element_text(family="serif", size = 8),
legend.text = element_text(family="serif", size = 8),
plot.title = element_text(family="serif", face="bold", size = 8, hjust = 0.5)) +
ggtitle("(f)")+
new_scale_color() +
geom_line(data=iris,  aes(x= Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color="Gold"), size=1)+
scale_color_manual(name = "Colour", values = c("Gold" = "gold"))
# +theme_classic()+scale_linetype_manual(values=bplot6, name="Data Source: ", labels=c("Ceres", "Landsat", "FAO"))+ theme(legend.position = "bottom")

bplot6
```